# Shape key Pivot point ignores initial edit pivot

Tags: animation, shape-keys

https://clipchamp.com/watch/ALoZTrgBSix

Can't get shapes like these animated properly because the shape keys completely ignore the pivot point of the object and do whatever that is instead.
is there a way to control the way shape keys are animated or should i try something else?

Comment: Shapekeys will interpolate between shape A and shape B, it will go straight forwards, why don't you use the bones instead?

Comment: .. shape keys are linear (translations) , they will always 'cut the corners' on a rotation. you could use bones, as @moonboots suggests, or if not for export, a driven modifier?  (Screw, GN ? )

Comment: @moonboots thanks yet again, I just wanted to try out shape keys but I guess the bones will have to do.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for the intel, I'll use the bones instead.